# iOS App with Swift5 is not compatible with the ios 10.3 version

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have develop one app in the latest **xcode (11.1)** with swift 5 and have a **mac OS version (10.14.6**). When I try to installed this app build on iOS version **10.3** through the testflight public link , then it says 
   **"This App isn't compatible with this device".** But works in 11, 11.2 , 13.1.3 etc.

Please help me to solve this issue.

I tried lower the deployment target from the xcode build setting but app is not installing in to the device having the version 10.3 and lower.

Is there any way to have one build with the latest swift and work in all the version's of iOS.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Comment: In Build Settings make sure on Release "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to No.

Comment: In the "Build Active Architecture"  Debug is set as YES and Release is set as NO

Comment: From the internet and personal experience:   When creating the archive (using the Product/Archive command) you must use the "Build Only Device - Generic iOS Device" at the top left on Xcode rather than pointing to a 64 bit device attached to the computer.  This is the case even though you have "Build Active Architecture Only" set to "NO".

Comment: are you using swift UI?

Comment: The Build Only Device is set as "Generic iOS Device" and Am not using swift UI.